# Run entirely a python code in IOS app?

Tags: python, ios, xcode

I have some code written in Python. I would like to know if it's possible to make a ios app which can execute the python code ?

For example, let's say I have a python code which can classify some picture into different categories by printing the correct category.
I would like to create an ios app which take in input the images, these images are given to the python code, the python code is executed and the result is printed thank to a print function in Objective C.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use this framework https://github.com/pybee/Python-Apple-support 
Check your python version first then Add header and framework search paths.